# CSS Solution to image rendering

Tags: css, image-manipulation

I have an zoomable image in the website. When the image is zoomed out to a large extend it appears very SHARP and ugly.

I tried using image-rendering : opimizequality, optimizespeed CSS but did not work.

Is there any other way out.

Thanks

Comment: In which browser did you try?

Comment: firefox... I'm okay if it works just for firefox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [`image-rendering` on MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/image-rendering), `image-rendering` is currently only supported in Firefox 3.6.  A similar property, `-ms-interpolation-mode`, is available for IE7 and IE8.  Other browsers don't seem to have this feature (yet).

As [latze mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267030/css-solution-to-image-rendering/3267048#3267048), your best bet is to edit the image itself, scaling it to the level you need.  I'm not sure, but you may try using `<canvas>` to perform the interpolation you desire.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply edit the picture instead of the CSS.

Try making the picture slightly larger step by step while you make sure the picture doesn't (as we call it in danish, not sure if it correct english) "pixelate".

This can be done in various image editing programs from The Gimp-shop to Photoshop.

Comment: Oh! I just read the question again and realised I've answered the question as if youre problem was that the picture got UNsharp when zooming in - sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Images aren't meant to be resized that much. Think about an image as a graph where each pixel is a single square in the graph. If you stretch the image out, you're essentially making the pixels stretch out. Some programs *try* to fill in these pixels with what they think would fit there, others just make the pixel bigger, and others just fill in the surrounding areas with the same pixels to give it a sort of glowish effect. Resizing images down, while it tends to work better, also creates the same effect, because you're just chopping off pixels instead of adding them. Most programs that I've seen will squish pixels together, combining whichever colors were in those pixels. If you have a high detail image, then chopping off pixels is going to make it look horrible. There are no really safe ways to determine which pixels need to be retained to keep the overall image in tact. Most websites that have zoom features have a much larger image which has been resized down and they let you zoom to view the details of the larger image. Some even get separate images of the massive detailed one and the smaller preview one.